# How to calculate partial derivative using chain rule?

Tags: partial-derivative, chain-rule

I have a function:

$${{\mathop{\rm F}\nolimits} _i}\left( {\bf{\xi }} \right) = \sum\limits_k^N {{\mathop{\rm D}\nolimits} \left( {\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_j^N {{\mathop{\rm G}\nolimits} \left( {j,{\mathop{\rm I}\nolimits} \left( {j,{\bf{\xi }}} \right)} \right)}  - {\mathop{\rm G}\nolimits} \left( {k,{\mathop{\rm I}\nolimits} \left( {k,{\bf{\xi }}} \right)} \right)} \right)}$$

$${\rm F}_i(\xi)=\sum_k^N {\rm D}_k\left(\frac1N\sum_j^N{\rm G}_j({\rm I}_j(\xi))-{\rm G}_k({\rm I}_k(\xi))\right).$$

$\xi$ is a vector.

How do I calculate the partial derivative using the chain rule?

$$\frac{\partial{\rm F}_i}{\partial\xi}=? $$

I guess...

$$\frac{\partial{\rm F}_i}{\partial\xi}=\sum_k^N\frac{\partial{\rm F}_i}{\partial{\rm D}_k}\left(\frac1N\sum_j^N\frac{\partial {\rm D}_k}{\partial {\rm G}_j}\frac{\partial {\rm G}_j}{\partial {\rm I}_j}\frac{\partial {\rm I}_j}{\partial \xi}-\frac{\partial {\rm D}_k}{\partial {\rm G}_k}\frac{\partial {\rm G}_k}{\partial {\rm I}_k}\frac{\partial {\rm I}_k}{\partial \xi}\right). $$

- full version

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBOTf.jpg)

Comment: Question: are the ${\rm D}_k$ functions of $\xi?$ Comment: your $\LaTeX$ typesetting is a bit constipated. See my edits for an improvement, and nearly equivalent result.

Comment: Sorry, I was not friendly with the LATEX, so I convert from the Mathtype. I'll practice latex. F, D, G, I are functions of xi.

Comment: No problem! One more question: is the ${\rm D}_k$ a function applied to the sum over $j$, or is it regular multiplication?

Comment: um.. I don't understand your question. The index k means different constant parameter. like this Dk(...) = D(k, ...).

Comment: For one thing, if $F_i(\xi)$ is a function of one variable, then you are taking an ordinary derivative, not a partial. In fact, unless there are hidden variables you haven't indicated (If so, please edit! We can't read your mind.), *all* of the derivatives involved are ordinary derivatives.

Comment: Crucially though, you are using the chain rule incorrectly. 

$$\frac{d}{dx}[f(g(x)] = f^\prime(g(x))\cdot g^\prime(x)$$

Comment: Your image is considerably more complicated than what you wrote down and excludes the norm entirely. You can't ignore this when taking derivatives.

Comment: sorry, I uploaded the full formula by picture. mathtype converting not working.

Comment: There's not enough information here.

Comment: The last line of the image makes no sense given the definition of $r_i$.

Comment: Is it possible to replace norm with some simple function D?

Comment: Sure, but that's just a relabeling. You still have to take the derivative of the norm. With the number of parameters involved this derivative is going to be *very* complicated.

Comment: I can use L1-norm instead of L2-norm... It just vector -> scalar converting.

Answer (score 1):

$${\rm F}^\prime_i(\xi)=\sum_k^N {\rm D}^\prime_k\left(\frac1N\sum_j^N\left({\rm G}_j({\rm I}_j(\xi))-{\rm G}_k({\rm I}_k(\xi))\right)\right)\cdot \frac1N\sum_j^N\left({\rm G}^\prime_j({\rm I}_j(\xi)){\rm I}^\prime_j(\xi)-{\rm G}^\prime_k({\rm I}_k(\xi)){\rm I}^\prime_k(\xi)\right)$$

Edit: This is the derivative of what was originally asked about but is certainly not the same as the derivative of the function contained in the image of the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think the total derivative chain rule is easiest to remember:

$$D_{f\circ g}(x) = D_f(g(x)) \cdot D_g(x)$$

What the $D$'s look like $($as $m\times n$ matrices$)$ of course depends on the domain and codomain of each function.